# plugin that works in DEV and UAT but not in Production?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a plugin that works in DEV and UAT but not in Production. And also it not showing any error

Can any one help out how debug this type of issue

Comment: debug using Plugin Profiler

Comment: Can you share some details? StackOverflow != MS Support...